# Loop through data to create a dictionary with key/value pairs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, rows

I'm trying to modify some Javascript code to create objects from each row and assign these objects their corresponding key/value pairs. I have not been able to figure this out.

My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Persons      name    surname      profession
ID Sally     Sally   Smith        Developer
ID John      John    Appleseed    Accountant
```

What I have achieved is to create objects like so, but as you can see, the first object has the properties of the last row in the spreadsheet:

```
export const id_sally = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Appleseed",
    profession: "Accountant"
};

export const id_john = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Appleseed",
    profession: "Accountant"
};
```

Here is the code:

```
// Find Keys start cell and build array of Person IDs
const personIDs = [];
let headerRowNumber = 0;
sheetData.forEach((row, rowNumber) => {
    if (row[0] === config.personKeysStartCell) {
        headerRowNumber = rowNumber;
        let i = 1;
        for (let i = 1; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
            // Here sheetData[i][0] refers to all the DOM names of the persons
            let personName = sheetData[i][0];
            personIDs.push({
                name: personName.toLowerCase(),
                columnIndex: i
            });
        }
    }
});

// Build a dictionary of key/value pairs for each personID
const dictionary = {};
for (const person of personIDs) {
    dictionary[person.name] = {};
}

const data = [];

sheetData.forEach(i => {
    data.push(i);
});

const personDomNames = data[0];

sheetData.forEach((row, rowNumber) => {
    if (row[0] && rowNumber > headerRowNumber) {
        for (const ad of personIDs) {
            for (let i = 1; i < personDomNames.length; i++) {
                dictionary[person.name][personDomNames[i]] = row[i];
            }
        }
    }
});

// Write each dictionary to its own es6 module file
let personArray = [];
for (const person in dictionary) {
    let output = `export const ${person} = {\n`;
    for (const key in dictionary[person]) {
        const value = dictionary[person][key];
        if (value && isNaN(value)) {
            output += `    ${key}: "${value}",\n`;
        } else if (!isNaN(value) && value !== "") {
            output += `    ${key}: ${value},\n`;
        } else {
            output += `    ${key}: undefined,\n`;
        }
    }
    output += `};\n\n`;
    personArray.push(output);
}
const filePath = `${config.outputDir}/personsInventory.js`;
fs.writeFile(filePath, personArray.join(""), error => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log(`${filePath} generated.`);
    }
});
```

I'd appreciate some help here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you will read the spreadsheet range?

Comment: I'm getting this from a config.js file, which is properly set @Rubén

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to convert the following Spreadsheet values as follows.

  - From

    ```
    Persons name    surname profession
    Sally   Sally   Smith   Developer
    John    John    Appleseed   Accountant
    ```
  - To

    ```
    {
      "ID Sally": {"name": "Sally", "surname": "Smith", "profession": "Developer"},
      "ID John": {"name": "John", "surname": "Appleseed", "profession": "Accountant"}
    }
    ```
- You want to achieve this using Node.js.
- You have already been able to get the values from Spreadsheet.

  - The values of `sheetData` in your script is as follows.

    ```
    [
      ["Persons","name","surname","profession"],
      ["ID Sally","Sally","Smith","Developer"],
      ["ID John","John","Appleseed","Accountant"]
    ]
    ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

```js
var sheetData = [["Persons","name","surname","profession"],["ID Sally","Sally","Smith","Developer"],["ID John","John","Appleseed","Accountant"]];

// Sample script for converting the values from Spreadsheet to a dictionary.
var header = sheetData.shift();
header.shift();
var dictionary = sheetData.reduce(function(obj1, row) {
  var value = row.shift();
    obj1[value] = header.reduce(function(obj2, f, j) {
    obj2[f] = row[j];
    return obj2;
  }, {});
  return obj1;
}, {});
console.log(dictionary);


// Write each dictionary to its own es6 module file
let personArray = [];
for (const person in dictionary) {
    let output = `export const ${person} = {\n`;
    for (const key in dictionary[person]) {
        const value = dictionary[person][key];
        if (value && isNaN(value)) {
            output += `    ${key}: "${value}",\n`;
        } else if (!isNaN(value) && value !== "") {
            output += `    ${key}: ${value},\n`;
        } else {
            output += `    ${key}: undefined,\n`;
        }
    }
    output += `};\n\n`;
    personArray.push(output);
}
console.log(personArray);
```

- In above sample script, `dictionary` can be used for `dictionary` in your script.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.